# Query returns one post late

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I have a query that gets all the posts in the database. Say I post a post, it won't show, till I post another post. So essentially there's a post delay, until you post another post. That's the best I can explain it. Here's my query

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_post_id = :id
```

Then I create an array

```
//Get post comments
$cmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_post_id = :id");
$cmt->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$cmt->execute();
$cmtc = $cmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$comments = array();
while($row = $cmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $comments[] =  array(
        'comment_user' => $row['comment_user'],
        'comment_ip' => $row['comment_ip'],
        'comment_date' => $row['comment_date'],
        'comment_content' => $row['comment_content'],
        'comment_post_id' => $row['comment_post_id']
    );
}
```

And finally display it

```
<?php foreach($comments as $comment){?>
<h1 class="message"><?php echo $comment['comment_content']?></h1>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm not getting any errors, but when I run the query in the command line I get one result. But when I visit the page I don't see any results.

Here's the structure

```
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| comment_user    | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_ip      | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_date    | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_content | varchar(85)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| comment_post_id | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: what's the output of `print_r($comments)` right after your while? Is it showing the content?

Comment: Returning nothing @dognose

Comment: But then when I post another comment and do `print_r` I get an array @dognose

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe you're holding a transaction open that's preventing a commit. You probably want to have a look in your database and make sure the comments are committed properly.

Comment: The query works fine when I do `SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_post_id = 75`, for example. I'd get that one comment, then when I check out the page it's not there. @tadman

Comment: You're not using transactions of any kind? You're also not caching the page in any way? Just going through the usual diagnostics here.

Comment: No, and I'm using APC, but I've also had the issue before enabling it. @tadman

Comment: Can you show a full code example? In your snippet above we're not seeing where `$cmt` is coming from

Comment: Provide database schema aswell please.

Comment: You are not running a master/slave database setup are you? Sounds like replication lag to me.

Comment: Database schema and also, the rest of the script.

Comment: Added in my post @ClémentMalet

Comment: I don't believe so @oliakaoil

Comment: I added all of the essential code, and the scheme @sensorario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first call to fetch automatically increments the internal pointer of the result set by one after fetching the row:

```
$cmtc = $cmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The above returns the zeroth row and moves the pointer to the first row. So, when you get to your while loop, the pointer is offest by one, and nothing is found:

```
while($row = $cmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that line:

```
$cmtc = $cmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You should simple remove it.

Otherwise you fetch first record and don't assign it to `$comments` variable and then in loop you try to get records from 2 to n

Answer (score 1):

To fetch all results of your query try this:

```
$cmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id = :id");
$cmt->bindValue(':id', 1);
$cmt->execute();
$comments = $cmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

PS. your schema use id as primary key, but your query use comment_post_id.